# Slim templates: How to rescue an exception?

Tags: ruby, erb, slim-lang

I would like to convert the following erb code into slim.

```
<% begin %>
  <%= some_function %>
<% rescue Exception %>
  <%= some_other_function %>
<% end%>
```

My approach is:

```
- begin 
  = some_function
- rescue Exception 
  = some_other_function
```

But that gives an error:

```
index.slim:34: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end
```

How do I rescue exceptions properly using slim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually a [bug in slim](https://github.com/slim-template/slim/issues/374) and is fixed in slim 1.3.7 upwards (https://github.com/slim-template/slim/commit/e4df090c2c82c3563bcc4e625cbd6ab55a60caf8)

The syntax now works exactly as expected. No helper method nor indenting is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

You need to make a Helper.

It's in that helper that you should put begin/rescue logic.

```
# my_helper.rb
class MyHelper
  def my_func
    begin
      some_function
    rescue
      some_other_func
    end
  end
end

# slim view
= my_func
```

Comment: Luckily this is not necessary anymore, see answer below.